# Webhooks not receiving Uber callback

Tags: uber-api

I have configured my application to receive callbacks on sandbox request api status changes, but I have not been receiving any call to my webhook url. I have been able to test my web hook url with a post and it works so I dont think its the url that is the cause of the issue.

Note I am able to change the status through a Put request to the sandbox and afterwards on polling the request endpoint I see the status changes I made. Yet no call to my webhook url set in the config.

Note the url I used as the web hook in my app settings page is a subdomain with this format: https://subdomain.domain.com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/

Comment: Hey! I work on the Developer Platform Team at Uber and we would love to help debug your issue. Email your client ID to us at developer@uber.com and we'll help debug.

Comment: Thank you, I have sent my client id via email, and also dropped the link to this page as a reference.

Comment: Can you try to isolate if the issue is a setup problem with your server? Are you able to recreate the problem using http://requestb.in/ as your webhooks server?

Comment: Hi, I got an email of a request error generated by a post from the uber api to my web hook. Now I can debug the issue on my server, it seems I am not handling the sent data properly. This is the first time my web hook is receiving a request from the sandbox. Thank you again

Comment: Hi I tried using the request.in link but the web hook field will not accept a link that is not secure (http - request.in only generates http links), so i am stuck. Note I got an email indicating that my web hook was sent a curl request earlier in the day, I am assuming it was being tested on your end (I didn't initiate it, the last time i used the sandbox was a few days back) and the only reason my web hook url threw an error was because it expects the content-type application/json to be set on all incoming requests.

Comment: We are facing a similar issue on Production environment. Tried sending an email to developer@uber.com, but it bounced. Can you provide an alternate email id where we can contact you?

Answer (score 1):

I found out you don't get the responses back unless you have a CA signed certificate installed on your server. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a CA certificate and when i run a check it shows it is in order, the issue I have is that I don't seem to get any requests coming from Uber sandbox, I look through my logs. The only day I got a request was one my endpoint was when curl was used to send a request, I assume for testing my complaint( Troubleshooting from their end).