# Uber sandbox api returns duplicate ride request id for mutiple ride requests

Tags: uber-api

I have created a session with sandbox_mode = True, with all scopes, including request, using uber_rides python library. The api calls work fine, but I get duplicate request_ids for mutiple ride requests(fired one after the other, and not concurrent). Though these requests are using the same lat, longs and product_id. Can it be possible that uber creates a ride id using lat, long ?
Is this okay ? Or am I actually missing something, and this should never happen ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you might be running into is that if you are already on a trip and you try to create a new one, the API will just return the trip details for your current trip. So I think what is happening is you're creating one trip, then trying to create another and you're getting back a "processing" status so it looks like you created a new trips, but its actually still the first trip.

You can verify this by creating a trip, checking the UUID, canceling the trip, then requesting a new one and seeing if the UUID is different.

Best,
   Riche

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Though now I am facing an issue with the webhook callbacks (not receiving callback on my self signed https server). There is a question for this issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606023/webhooks-not-receiving-uber-callback But no concrete answers. Would you be kind enough to give it a thought ?

Comment: Hey Harsh, I think the issue you're having is that you're using a self-signed certificate. Our webhooks will only post to servers signed with CA certificates.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Will use CA signed certificate and try again.

Comment: For getting a CA signed certificate I recommend [Let’s Encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt) which is a free, automated, and open certificate authority (CA), run for the public’s benefit.

Answer (score 0):

- product_id is based on the start_latitude/start_longitude or start_place_id parameters.
- request_id is not (it's just a UUID identifying the ride request)

If you are doing multiple ride requests with the same OAuth Bearer token and you do not cancel the first ongoing ride request you are basically getting back the status details of the current ongoing trip.

According to [Uber Help - CAN I REQUEST MORE THAN ONE UBER?](https://help.uber.com/h/2ca87e87-5ea9-4322-a5c8-dc1b046791f9)

> At this time, it’s not possible to request more than one ride from a
>   single account.
>
> If your party cannot be accommodated by a single vehicle, have
>   multiple people in your group request rides. We offer vehicle options
>   accommodating up to 6 people in many cities.
>
> If no one else in your group has an Uber account, you can invite them
>   to sign up from the main menu of your app. As a bonus, both you and
>   your friend will receive the referral promotion.

This also applies to the Uber API.

However, from my use of the Uber API I've noticed the following rate limiting headers sent back on some responses:

> - X-Rate-Limit-Limit-Concurrent-Trips: 10
> - X-Rate-Limit-Remaining-Concurrent-Trips: 10

so they probably plan to add the possibility of making concurrent ride requests from the same Uber rider.